# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using this code to move and resize the button in a relative layout...

Program crashes when I touch on the screen, what can be the reason.?

```
    ViewGroup relativeL;


onCreate(){
relativeL = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    relativeL.setOnTouchListener(new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            methodMove();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void methodMove(){
    View button = findViewById(R.id.helloButton);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(relativeL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    relativeL.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(130,250));
}
```

I have tried making relative layout as just RelativeLayout type instead of ViewGroup, still didnot work. Guidance,...thank you in advance..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="my context"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/helloButton"/>
```

Comment: try changing to FrameLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: what's the parent layout of helloButton

Comment: it is in same activity....its parent layiout is relative layout only...

Comment: post your xml layout please

Comment: If the layout you're putting it into is a FrameLayout, then you have to make a FrameLayout.LayoutParmas, not a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: my layout is relative layout

Comment: Please post the entire code of your activity, not just the bit you're currently showing,  Also post the entire stack trace of an error any time you have one available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mobile and I can't check the code but could you try changing

```
button.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(130,250));
```

To

```
button.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(130,250));
```